# Inserting data in table database Wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am currently working on a piece of code that inserts data from a recent upload in the database. I tried different ways to make it work, however it does not work.

I tried the following at first:

```
$upload = ftp_put($conn_id, $destination_file, $source_file, FTP_BINARY);
// check upload status 
if (!$upload) { 
echo "Er is iets fout gegaan, excuses voor het ongemak";
} else {
  $sql = "INSERT INTO table (id, name) VALUES (1, 'Cake')";
  var_dump(error_get_last($sql));
```

The `var_dump(error_get_last($sql));` returns NULL. I do not know why, a connection is not needed since Wordpress automatically makes a connection with the database.

I also tried the following:

```
$upload = ftp_put($conn_id, $destination_file, $source_file, FTP_BINARY);
// check upload status 
if (!$upload) { 
echo "Er is iets fout gegaan, excuses voor het ongemak";
} else {
// insert data in de database
$sql = "INSERT INTO $wpdb->wpex_programma (id, naam) VALUES (2, 'Country Kickin 2')";
$prepare_query = $wpdb->prepare($sql);
$result = $wpdb->sql($prepare_query);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
```

Normally, when a user uploads a file, the user can view his file on the page. Because of this code, that was not possible anymore. I do not know how to solve it.

This is the whole if and else statement:

```
if ((!$conn_id) || (!$login_result)) { 
    echo "Het spijt ons, er is momenteel geen connectie met de server.";
    // echo "Attempted to connect to $ftp_server for user $ftp_user_name"; 
    exit; 
} else {
     // echo "upload is gelukt";
}

// upload het bestand
$upload = ftp_put($conn_id, $destination_file, $source_file, FTP_BINARY);
// check upload status 
if (!$upload) { 
echo "Er is iets fout gegaan, excuses voor het ongemak";
} else {
// insert data in de database
$sql = "INSERT INTO $wpdb->wpex_programma (id, naam) VALUES (2, 'Country Kickin 2')";
$prepare_query = $wpdb->prepare($sql);
$result = $wpdb->sql($prepare_query);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);

// weergeef het bestand & download
    $contents = ftp_nlist($conn_id, $destination_folder);
    // doe dit aan als er ergens een error is: var_dump(error_get_last($contents));

   foreach ($contents as $mp3_url) { 
    $filename = basename($mp3_url, ".mp3");
// dit zorgt ervoor dat de punten niet te zien zijn.
if($filename == "..") {
  continue;
  print_r($filename);
}

if($filename == ".") {
  continue;
  print_r($filename);
}
?>
```

Also, the $result variable returns NULL when `var_dump(error_get_last($result));`

EDIT:

I changed:

```
else {
// insert data in de database
$sql = "INSERT INTO $wpdb->wpex_programma (id, naam) VALUES (2, 'Country Kickin 2')";
$prepare_query = $wpdb->prepare($sql);
$result = $wpdb->sql($prepare_query);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
```

to:

```
else {

    // insert data in de database
global $wpdb

$number_of_rows_inserted = $wpdb->insert('wpex_programma', [
  'naam' => 'Country kickin 2'
]);
var_dump($number_of_rows_inserted);
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO $wpdb->wpex_programma (id, naam) VALUES (2, 'Country Kickin 2')";
$prepare_query = $wpdb->prepare($sql);
$result = $wpdb->sql($prepare_query);
```

with

```
$number_of_rows_inserted = $wpdb->insert('wpex_programma', [
   'id' => 2,
   'naam' => 'Country kickin 2'
]);

var_dump($number_of_rows_inserted);
```

The `insert` method is doing the prepare so y ou don't need it.

Add `global $wpdb;` at the start of your function or file if it's not done. Also, try to remove the line `'id' => 2` as the id should be set to auto increment.

Comment: Hello, please see the new edit in my question. The upload form dissapears. Do you mean I should write my code like in the new edit?

Comment: well remove `print_r($results)` as i didn't set it in my code and tell me what's happing then

Comment: Oops, did not see that. Ok I deleted it, the upload form still does not show however. Is the ````global $wpdb```` in the correct place right there?

Comment: It should not cause any problems. But my code has nothing to do with the upload form. Do you have WP_DEBUG set to true ? What's on the screen ?

Comment: Ooh, I forgot to put a ````;```` behind the ````$global wpdb````

Comment: I think the other solution here may works but the table name was not okay 
 : `"INSERT INTO $wpdb->wpex_programma"` shoud be `"INSERT INTO {$wpdb->prefix}programma"`

Comment: @AlexisVandepitte thank you for pointing out, I just copied that part from the question :-) I updated my answer as it might be good to show multiple ways of inserting

Answer (score 0):

You are using a non-existent method (`$wpdb->sql()`)on the `wpdb` object.

Use `$wpdb->query()` to execute your `INSERT` query.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO {$wpdb->prefix}programma (id, naam) VALUES (2, 'Country Kickin 2')";
$query = $wpdb->prepare($sql);
$result = $wpdb->query($query);
var_dump($result); // int(1) on success OR bool(false) on failure
```

Comment: Thank you, the files are displayed on the browser. However, they do not get inserted in the DB table and the font type somehow changed.

Comment: They are not inserted in the database table because you always insert the same record: `2, 'Country Kickin 2'`

Comment: The font probably changed because you echo a `<pre>` tag

Comment: Ok, let me try with a different record.

Comment: I it tried with a different record: ````$sql = "INSERT INTO $wpdb->wpex_programma (id, naam) VALUES (3, 'Country Kickin 3')";````. But it still does not work.